# Character Analyzer Stuck

Tags: java

I dont want someone to tell me how to do this completely but I need to be able to print out whether the char is an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, or a number and what its ASCII is. Like I said I dont want the answer I just want to know how to start this. My teacher wont help me and the people sitting next to me are just as confused as I am. I would really appreciate so help.

Thanks in advance!

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharacterAnalyzer
{
private char theChar;

public CharacterAnalyzer()
{
theChar = 0;

}

public CharacterAnalyzer(char c)
{
theChar = c;

}

public void setChar(char c)
{

}

public char getChar()
{
    return '-';

}

public boolean isUpper( )
{
    return false;

}

public boolean isLower( )
{
    return false;

}

public boolean isNumber( )
{
    return false;

}   

public int getASCII( )
{
    return 0;
}

public String toString()
{
    return ""+getChar() + " is a lowercase character. ASCII == " + getASCII() + "\n";     
}
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    out.print("Enter a letter :: ");
    char letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    CharacterAnalyzer test = new CharacterAnalyzer(letter);
    out.println(test);
```

Comment: I would suggest you start with the docs for the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, one way to implement `isUpper`:

```
public boolean isUpper( ) {
    return 'A' <= theChar && theChar <= 'Z';
}
```

Based on the logic in this, I hope you will be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

All characters are really just assigned to numbers.

If you check http://www.asciitable.com/ you will find that there are sequential orders to the lettering/numbering.

Based on this you should be able to figure out how to check which kind of character it is based on its `ascii` value.